# Extracted some JSON into a variable, now want to extract JSON from that variable into another variable

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

I have extracted a JSON snippet from a response body into `variable_A`. Now I want to extract some JSON from `variable_A` to be used within the request URL of an HTTP Request.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you did for the response body, but now configure [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to read not the response body, but rather specify `variable_A` in "JMeter Variable to Use" section:

[image]

Given `variable_A` is a [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/) you should be able to use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and extract "interesting" value(s) from it.

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)